# Inserting data into two database tables through Table tbody

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

What I'm trying to do is when I select number of products from dropdown it appears in below table. Now when i click Save button below the table, I want data to be insert in two Database table i.e Sales and SaleItems.
Well Data is inserting in Sales table but I don't know how to insert in another table SaleItems.
Please help me how can i do that?

Here's my code

```
 <table id="table" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Product Id</th>
                        <th scope="col">Company</th>
                        <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">User Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">User Mobile</th>
                        <th scope="col">Price per product</th>
                        <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                        <th scope="col">Total Price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
                <tfoot><tr><td colspan="2">Grand Total : </td><td id="GrandTotal"></td></tr></tfoot>
            </table>

 <script>
        $('#productSelect').change(function () {
            var id = $(this).val();

            if (id > 0) {
                $.get("GetProduct", { productId: id }, function (result) {
                    console.log(result)
                    $("tbody").append("<tr><td>" + result.ProductId + "</td><td>" + result.CompanyName + "</td><td>" + result.ProductName + "</td><td>" + result.UserName + "</td><td>" + result.UserMobile + "</td><td>" + result.ProductPrice + "</td><td><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onClick='subtract(" + id + "," + result.ProductPrice + ")'>-</button><button type='button' class='btn btn-dark'  id='" + id + "' value='0'>0</button><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onClick='add(" + id + "," + result.ProductPrice + ")'>+</button></td><td id='sum" + id + "'>0</td><td><a onclick='removeRow(this)'>x</a></td></tr>")
                      CalculateGrandTotal();
                    
                });
            }
        })

 $("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {
        //Loop through the Table rows and build a JSON array.
        var sales = new Array();
        $(".table tbody tr").each(function () {
            var row = $(this);
            var Sale = {};
            Sale.UserName = row.find("td").eq(3).html();
            Sale.UserMobile = row.find("td").eq(4).html();
            Sale.NetTotal = row.find("td").eq(8).html();
            Sale.ProductQuantity = row.find("td").eq(5).val();
            sales.push(Sale);
        });

 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Product/Insertsales",
            data: JSON.stringify(sales),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                alert(r + " records inserted.");
            }
        });

</script>
```

And Here's my Controller Code

```
public JsonResult InsertSales(List<Sale> sales)
        {
            using (sampledb6Entities sampledb6Entities = new sampledb6Entities())
            {
                //Truncate Table to delete all old records.
                //sampledb6Entities.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [Sales]");

                //Check for NULL.
                if (sales == null)
                {
                     sales = new List<Sale>();
                }

                //Loop and insert records.
                foreach (Sale sale in sales)
                {
                    sampledb6Entities.Sales.Add(sale);
                }
                int insertedRecords = sampledb6Entities.SaveChanges();
                return Json(insertedRecords);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create SaleItem objects by using Sale objects and insert them into the table

```
foreach (Sale sale in sales)
{   
   sampledb6Entities.Sales.Add(sale);
   SaleItem saleItem = ... // convert the sale to SaleItem object 
   sampledb6Entities.SaleItems.Add(saleItem);
}
int insertedRecords = sampledb6Entities.SaveChanges();
```